# Bash Script "Command Not Found Error"

Tags: bash

Im working on writing a bash script to download imgur albums for the purpose or learning bash. I have this much written so far but when I run it i get this output:

```
Enter the URL of the imgur album you would like to download: imgur.com
./imgur_dl.sh: line 25: Validating: command not found
./imgur_dl.sh: line 26: Getting: command not found
./imgur_dl.sh: line 30: imgur.com: command not found
```

This is my code so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

url=""
id=""

get_id(){
  echo "Getting Album ID..."
  local url=$1
  echo $url
  echo "Successflly got Album ID..."
  return
}

validate_input(){
  echo "Validating Input..."
  local id=$1
  echo $id
  echo "Input Validated Successfully..."
  return
}

get_input(){
  read -p "Enter the URL of the imgur album you would like to download: " url
  echo $url
  $(validate_input url)
  $(get_id url)
  return
}

$(get_input)
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I not getting?
I am working on macOS it that helps at all.

Comment: See [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) for more context.

Answer (score 2):

Just call the functions directly, like:

`valide_input $url`

and so on.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    url=""
    id=""

    get_id ()
    {
      echo "Getting Album ID..."
      local url=$1
      echo $url
      echo "Successflly got Album ID..."
      return
    }

    validate_input ()
    {
      echo "Validating Input..."
      local id=$1
      echo $id
      echo "Input Validated Successfully..."
      return
    }

    get_input ()
    {
      read -p "Enter the URL of the imgur album you would like to d        ownload: " url
      echo $url
      validate_input $url
      get_id $url
      return
    }

    get_input
```

Also, as someone else suggested, you can make this better by putting the $Url inside double quotes, like

`validate_input "$url"`

So it handles otherwise invalid urls.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. Any quick way to format a block at once?

Comment: Highlight the code then click the `Code Sample` button.

Comment: @imerso: or highlight the code and press `Ctrl`+`k`.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax means, *execute the output of `get_id url` as shell command*:

> ```
> $(get_id url)
> ```

In current implementation the output of `get_id url` is this:

```
Getting Album ID...
url
Successflly got Album ID...
```

And this gets executed as shell commands,
producing the error message:

> ```
> ./imgur_dl.sh: line 26: Getting: command not found
> ```

Because indeed there is no such shell command "Getting".

---

I think you want to do something like this:

```
local id=$(get_id "$url")
```

Where `get_id` is a function that takes a URL and uses that URL to get some id, and then `echo` that id.
The function should look something like this:

```
get_id() {
    local url=$1
    local id=...
    echo id
}
```

That is:

- You need to remove other `echo` statements like the `echo "Getting ..."` stuff
- You need to actually implement getting an id, because the function currently doesn't do that.

The same goes for the other functions too.

---

Here's something to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

is_valid_url() {
    local url=$1
    # TODO
}

input_url() {
    local url
    while true; do
        read -p "Enter the URL of the imgur album you would like to download: " url
        if is_valid_url "$url"; then
            echo "$url"
            return
        fi
        echo "Not a valid url!" >&2
    done
}

download() {
    local url=$1
    echo "will download $url ..."
    # TODO
}

main() {
    url=$(input_url)
    download "$url"
}

main
```

Comment: The correct solution, but not a technically accurate description of [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution).